# Field related to field of related object Django

Tags: django

How can i make field related to field of related model. I have two models: album and photo, album model have boolean field `private`. How to create field `private` in photo, which will have `False` value if album field equal to None and value of album private field if it's not.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import os
import uuid

def get_image_path(instance, filename):
    return '{}.{}'.format(uuid.uuid4(), filename.split('.')[-1])


class Album(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='albums', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=80, default='New album')
    creation_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    private = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-creation_date', ]

class Photo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,  related_name='photos', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, related_name='photos', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=80, default='New photo')
    image = models.ImageField(title, upload_to=get_image_path)
    creation_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    # ???
    private = models.BooleanField()
    # ???

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-creation_date', ]
```

Comment: Can't you just add a property that depends on Album's private field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @RodXavier said just use property

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,  related_name='photos', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, related_name='photos', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=80, default='New photo')
    image = models.ImageField(title, upload_to=get_image_path)
    creation_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    @property
    def private(self):
        return getattr(self, 'album', False)
```

Comment: but i can't use filter with this approach.

Comment: @Robin Yes. You can't. There is one solution that will work for both lookups and filtering, which you didn't mention in your question, this is one solves the one you were asking